# Gammu incoming messages not stored in "Inbox" table

Tags: sms-gateway, gammu

I make an sms-gateway app using Windows 7, XAMPP/PHP/MySQL, Gammu 1.33, Modem Wavecom 1306B.
My problem is why incoming messages not stored in Inbox table?? Even try `getallsms` via CLI there's nothing.

All configuration are set, modem identified, service running, send sms manual via CLI or PHP script also OK (stored in Outbox then moved into SentItems).

I wanna use RunOrReceive to make auto-reply function but even simple incoming messages not stored in database.

Here's my smsd configuration http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NvZQ3aii

Am I miss something? Thanks

Comment: Any errors in the log?

Comment: @MichalČihař in gammrc, i turn on the log but logfile is empty. in smsdrc, gammu log was turn off, smsdlog turn on but no logs since previous month (October) when my trial and error to send sms.

Comment: When the log is empty, maybe gammu just doesn't find your configuration file...

Comment: @MichalČihař hmm... but when i run `gammu --identify` there's no problem :(
anyway, here my [gammurc](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Ghgv7nUx)

Comment: @MichalČihař OH sorry Michal my fault! Logfile going empty because I comment `logformat`. Now here logfile [content](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Y9CUYkjZ)

Comment: Try adding Features = USE_SMSTEXTMODE to the config as suggested in the log...

Comment: @MichalČihař okay, will try it. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @MichalČihař still no luck :(
i add `features = USE_SMSTEXTMODE` in gammurc and smsdrc. Running `gammu-smsd -c smsdrc` to check for the change, occur `CheckingSecurityStatus` error. Uncomment in smsdrc and set it to 0. It disappear, test send sms to modem again and my smsdlog size going bigger so fast! Here few lines of [smsdlog](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AwCwYiuJ) error. Full log [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByzA788sqkK1UGtJMTRnMk04NFU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything obvious and this definitely doesn't improve the situation. You can try luck with newer Gammu build (see https://github.com/gammu/gammu/issues/125)

Comment: @MichalČihař okay thanks to suggest, maybe later coz i dont know to do CMAKE in windows lol. But can you see once more my [new smsdlog](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tENb596N) ?? Using v1.30 and there somethin interesting.
`Forcibily enabled SMS text mode` but in the end `WARNING: Used messages according to CPMS 3, but CMGL returned 0. Expect problems!`
Thanks

Comment: There is link to built binary in that issue..

Comment: @MichalČihař sorry, i already try use it but fail connect to MySQL. Anyway, i try and try again, change port and then i have different error now. `CMS Error 321: "invalid memory index"` Maybe it help. Hope I can fix this :(

Comment: @MichalČihař and actually, how to use `F_USE_SMSTEXTMODE` mode flag?? I mean, where i sud put it? Is it right to put it into gammurc / smsdrc file with `feature = USE_SMSTEXTMODE` line?

Comment: Yes, to the [gammu] section of the config file.